# why can use setTimeout("1")

Tags: javascript, settimeout

While reading source code, I saw a line

```js
console.log(setTimeout("1"))
```

and this code has return  a random number.

I don't know why. Please help me.

Comment: setTimeout returns an intervalID... perhaps reviewing [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) on the return value will answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout),

> The returned timeoutID is a numeric, non-zero value which identifies the timer created by the call to setTimeout(); this value can be passed to Window.clearTimeout() to cancel the timeout.

So when you do `= setTimeout()`, you are not getting value of something that you have passed, but it a system generated identifier.

`setTimeout` registers an event in event heap after specified delay. If delay is not mentioned, it assumes as `0` but note, `setTimeout(notify, 0)` is not same as `notify()`.

Also `setTimeout` expects a function as first parameter. When it receives a string, it assumes, you are passing function call as string and compiler tries to evaluate it using `eval`. So your `setTimeout("1")` will become `eval("1")` which will return `"1"` and hence you do not get error.

```js
function notify(){
  console.log('ta-da!!!');
}
var a = 10;

setTimeout("notify()",0)

// sample for eval
console.log(setTimeout("a"))

// This should throw error as `b` is not declared
console.log(setTimeout("b"))
```